# javascript keypress event and php

Tags: javascript, php

HTML code :

```
<td><input type="text"  name="flat[]" class="" value="<?php echo $row_pdetails["flat"]; ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text"  name="new_price[]" class="" value="<?php echo   $row_pdetails["price"]; ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text"  name="org_price[]" class="" value="<?php echo     $row_pdetails["org_price"]; ?>" readonly/></td>
<td><input type="submit"  name="save" value="save"/></td>
```

PHP code :

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["save"]))
  {
     for($i=0;$i<count($_POST["org_price"]); $i++)
     {
        $org_price=$_POST["org_price"][$i]; 
        $new_price=$_POST["new_price"][$i];
        mysql_query("update tb_party_rate_entry set price='$new_price' where   (party_id='$p_id' && org_price='$org_price')");
     }
  }
```

Here in this code I'm fetching the value of `new_price[]` and `org_price[]` from the database using a while loop, and for updating these values in the database I've used a for loop as in my PHP code.

Now what I want is that whenever I enter any value in `flat[]` textbox, that same value should simultaneously be entered in `new_price[]` textbox using keypress event. When I enter value in 1st row's flat price it should be entered in first row's `new_price[]`, when I enter value in 2nd row's flat price it should be entered in second row's `new_price[]`, and in keypress event.

Please help.

Comment: use `onchange` on the value of flat[] and assign the value of flat[] to new_price[]

Comment: for single row its working fine....but not working for multiple rows...that is the problem

Comment: You need to use a different id for each of flat[] and new_price[] pair.

Answer (score 0):

Test Here: http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/3/
**Html**

```
 <div>
    <tr>
        <td>flat1:<input type="text" name="flat[]" class="flat" value=""/></td>
        <td>price1:<input type="text" name="new_price[]" class="new_price" value=""/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="org_price[]" class="" value=""</td>
    </tr>
</div>
<div>
    <tr>
        <td>flat2:<input type="text" name="flat[]" class="flat" value=""/></td>
        <td>price2:<input type="text" name="new_price[]" class="new_price" value=""/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="org_price[]" class="" value=""</td>

    </tr>
</div>
<p><input type="submit" name="save" value="save"/></p>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.flat').on('keyup',function(e) {
       $( this ).siblings(".new_price").eq(0).val ( $(this).val() );
    });
});
```

Comment: did you try it? @user3138522

Comment: it is working but for example there are 10 rows ...each row contans flat and new_price...in first row...in flat i entered 20...it should be the value of new_price of that row....in second row i enter 30 in flat text textbox...then it should be value for taht row/s new_price...like this....

Comment: did you try the above link?

Comment: flat value will be show in the corresponding price field in same row . right?

Answer (score 0):

You should use onchange event on flat[] and set the value of new_price[] consequently.

Something like

```
$('input[name="flat[]"]').on('keyup',function(e) {
   $( this ).siblings('input[name="new_price[]"]:first').val ( $(this).val() );
});
```

Note: 
I used siblings because i assume you will have different rows with the same input name, in this way you only update the right element

Comment: how to put onchange event for this??

Answer (score 0):

[### FIDDLE (see demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/4/)

Try this:

note that i add `rel` attribute in html and created unique id for textbox.means every textbox have a unique id.

```
<?php 
$i = "1";
while(//$row=...){ 
?>
<td><input type="text"  name="flat[]" id="flat<?php echo $i;?>" rel="<?php echo $i;?>" class="flat" value="<?php echo $row_pdetails["flat"]; ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text"  name="new_price[]" id="newprice<?php echo $i;?>" rel="<?php echo $i;?>"  class="new_price" value="<?php echo   $row_pdetails["price"]; ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text"  name="org_price[]" id="orgprice<?php echo $i;?>" rel="<?php echo $i;?>" class="org_price" value="<?php echo $row_pdetails["org_price"]; ?>" readonly/></td>
<?php $i++;} ?>
<td><input type="submit"  name="save" value="save"/></td>
```

`JQuery:`

when user try to enter some thing in flat textbox, we get it's `rel` and it's value.using the rel's value we found related newprice textbox.

```
$(document).on('keyup','.flat',function(){
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    var flatvalue = $(this).val();
    $("#newprice"+rel).val(flatvalue);
});
```